# How to remove special char in golang when reading file?

Tags: go

I have a file like this:
[Each line represents a Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY4Ai.png)

```
1 www.google.com$
2 www.apple.com$
3 www.facebook.com$
```

I read it in golang like this:

```
type ListConf struct {
    File  string
    Datas map[string]struct{}
}

func loadListConf(conf *ListConf, path string) {
    file, err := os.Open(path + "/" + conf.File)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Load conf " + conf.File + " error: " + err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    conf.Datas = make(map[string]struct{})
    buf := bufio.NewReader(file)
    end := false
    for !end {
        line, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("Load conf " + conf.File + " error: " + err.Error())
                return
            } else {
                end = true
            }
        }
        item := strings.Trim(line, "\n")
        if item == "" {
            continue
        }
        conf.Datas[item] = struct{}{}
    }
}
```

But when I search key such like "www.google.com" in the map, it shows that there is not a "www.google.com" in the map.

```
website := "www.google.com"
if _, ok := conf.Datas[website]; ok {
    fmt.Printf("%s is in the map.", website)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("%s is not in the map.", website)
}
```

It print "www.google.com is not in the map".
I found that a ^M in the end of each key in the map, my question is how can I remove the ^M character?

```
www.google.com^M
www.apple.com^M
www.facebook.com^M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default line separator in text files on Windows is a sequence of two characters: `\r\n`. `^M` character that you see in your strings is `\r`.

[bufio.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) can take care of splitting the input into lines in a platform independent way:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error reading from the file:", err)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Less elegant but...

You can strip the `\r` from the end of the string with:

`line, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
        line = strings.TrimRight(line, "\r")`

It will remove multiple `\r` (^M) and is a no-op if there are none.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was missing. I just want to point out, that in your trim line (For Windows), I did this instead: line = strings.TrimRight(line, "\r\n")
.This was my solution to remove the special characters